# Does clojure repl store the return value of previous commands

Tags: java, memory-leaks, clojure, read-eval-print-loop

If I execute this commands in the clojure repl:

```
(take 5000000 (range))
```

This command prints out numbers upto 5 million (it takes some time) and the memory usage of clojure increases upto 750 MB during the execution `and it stays at that throughout the rest of the session`. Does the repl store the return value of previous commands or it's because of a memory leak in clojure?

Comment: Clojure retains some latest calls (2 or 3 if I remember well) but I guess it is more an issue with the JVM which does not give memory back to the OS (which is standard behaviour as far as I can tell). The memory may not be used but the space is kept. try your code several times silently and you will reach a peek.

Comment: @JosephYourine I tried it and the memory usage keeps on increasing on every invocation.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, [Clojure REPL retains the result of the last 3 expressions](https://clojure.org/reference/repl_and_main#_launching_a_repl):

> Several special vars are available when using the REPL:
>
> - *1, *2, *3 - hold the result of the last three expressions that were evaluated
> - *e - holds the result of the last exception

Once you execute more expressions and the result occupying so much memory is no longer referenced by one of the `*1`, `*2` and `*3`, then the next garbage collector run should reclaim that memory.